# Unexpected unrecoverable error in SQL Server Import

Tags: sql-server, excel, import

I'm trying to load a big Excel into SQL Server, but when I try to import, I always get an error

> Unexpected Unrecoverable Error

[image]

I wish I could provide more details. The import wizard always hangs right before throwing the error. I can also open and edit the file in Excel. I'm on a 64 bit system, but we only have 32 bit office installed.

Comment: Almost impossible to answer as is...   That said, consider exporting your excel to a tab delimited file or even a CSV

Comment: But what about all my number and date fields?  I have like 200 columns, most of them numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer I can give you is don't use Excel as a data source, ever. You will always stumble on issues like this. Not to mention data coming in unexpected formats because Excel does implicit conversions behind the scenes, which are often outside of user control.

As suggested by John in his comment, "Save As" your worksheet into a CSV or TSV text file(s), and import those instead.